# Showing martingale, submartingale or supermartingale with log

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Can somebody help me with determining whether $Z_{n}=\log(2n+S_{n})$ is a martingale, supermartingale or submartingale with $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and the are i.i.d. random variables with  $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

What I have so far is that 
$E[log(2n+S_{n})|F_{n-1}]\leq \log E[2n+S_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ by Jensen but now I am stuck in working to $Z_{n-1}$.

Comment: Obviously, $Z_{n+1}=\log(2+X_{n+1}+e^{Z_n})$ hence $E(Z_{n+1}\mid F_n)=\frac12\log(1+e^{Z_n})+\frac12\log(3+e^{Z_n})>Z_n$.

Comment: Why is the last inequality true?

Comment: Because $\log(1+e^z)>z$ and $\log(3+e^z)>z$, for every $z$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$ we have $2n+S_n>0$ a.s. so
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|Z_n|] &= \mathbb E[\log(2n+S_n)]\\
&\leqslant \log(\mathbb E[2n+S_n])\\
&= \log(2n + \mathbb E[S_n])\\
&= \log2 + \log n<\infty.
\end{align}
Further, 
\begin{align}
Z_{n+1} &= \log(2(n+1) + S_{n+1})\\
&= \log(2 + X_{n+1} + 2n + S_n)\\
&= \log(2 + X_{n+1} + e^{Z_n}),
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Z_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] &= \mathbb E[\log(2 + X_{n+1} + e^{Z_n})\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&= \mathbb E[\log(2 + X_{n+1} + e^{Z_n})\mid\mathcal F_n, X_{n+1}=-1]\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=-1) + \mathbb E[\log(2 + X_{n+1} + e^{Z_n})\mid\mathcal F_n, X_{n+1}=1]\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=1)\\
&= \frac12\mathbb E[\log(1+e^{Z_n})\mid\mathcal F_n] + \frac12\mathbb E[\log(3+e^{Z_n})\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&= \frac12\mathbb \log(1+e^{Z_n}) + \frac12\log(3+e^{Z_n})\\
&\geqslant \frac12Z_n + \frac12Z_n\\
&=Z_n,
\end{align}
so that $Z_n$ is a submartingale.